# Azure shows error ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/semver'\

Tags: reactjs, azure

I am receiving an error on Azure while getting it to build.
I have a react app and my azure is connected with bitbucket. So when I upload the changes to my bitbucket the Azure starts building and deploying the changes and fail with the errors in the following screenshot. I am not sure what is happening to it because I am new to Azure. Please guide me, guys! Thank you. [image: Error from Azure deployment logs]

Note: I have received the same kind of error on my windows env laptop when I build my react app locally, But I haven't received it on my Linux environment pc. Could it be possible that the files didn't copy properly when I tried to move the project through pen drive?. On my windows laptop, I receive this kind of error on npm run build but when I run the npm command three times it satrts building properly on the third time without any error.